# Weird issues with Edge when Bing is not the default search engine

Tags: windows-10, browser, microsoft-edge

I have been using the Edge browser on Windows 10 for a while, with Google configured as the default search engine and as the home page; it always worked fine.

Some days ago, several weird issues started happening:

- When launching the browser, it displays the "new tab" page instead of the home page.
- When right-clicking on some text, there is no option to search the web using the default search engine, but there is instead an option to search using Bing.
- When right-clicking on the Edge icon and choosing to start a new InPrivate window, the browser doesn't start at all; a new InPrivate window can only be opened if Edge is already running.
- When searching from the Start menu (which implicitly uses Bing), an additional tab with the "new tab" page is created along with the one with the search results.

**If I change the default search engine to Bing, all the issues disappear** (the second one obviously becomes not applicable).

This doesn't seem to depend on Google itself: if I select any default search engine which is not Bing, I have the same issues; only when Bing is selected as the default search engine everything works correctly.

I already tried resetting Edge to default settings, but it didn't solve the issues: if I change the default search engine, all the problems reappear.

The weirdest thing is, this only happens in my user profile; I tried creating a new user account on my computer, and Edge works correctly there: I can change the default search engine to Google and there are no issues at all.

How can I fix this?

Windows 10 x64 20H2, all the latest updates installed, Edge version 90.0.818.56 (latest).

Comment: The extra new tab page issue started appearing for me some days ago as well. Same version of Windows, same version of Edge. 

I synch my Edge profile and use it on a different pc with same version of Windows and Edge, but I don't experience these issues there. 

I also tried to add a new search engine template, that's an exact copy of the Bing search template `{bing:baseURL}search?q=%s&{bing:cvid}{google:assistedQueryStats}`, but I get the additional tab also when using this as search engine.

Is there a simple way to downgrade Edge, does anyone know?

Comment: One last comment from me. I only experience the additional tab bug, not the other things you describe. Still weird. Guess we'll just have to wait for version 91 and live with either the bugs or use Bing as search engine (no, not seriously).

Comment: The problem reappeared after an Edge update.
I'll try resetting Edge again.

Comment: Fixed again. Same problem, same solution.

Comment: Updated Edge to version 91.0.864.37 and the duplicate tabs issue disappeared for me. The 21H1 Windows 10 update got installed now as well, so not 100% certain what fixed it.

Comment: Then I rebooted, and the problem is back! This is really weird!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues were indeed related to my user profile; however, a normal Edge settings reset didn't fix them. I had to be a lot more thorough in fully resetting Edge to factory defaults, as discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1647721/how-to-fully-reset-edge).

Now Edge is behaving as it should and I can change my default search engine again without everything else going crazy.