# How to fully reset Edge?

Tags: windows-10, browser, user-profiles, microsoft-edge

I'm facing several weird issues with the Edge browser on Windows 10 (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1647708/weird-issues-with-edge-when-bing-is-not-the-default-search-engine)) which seem to be related to my user profile; if I create a new user account, Edge shows no issues.

I already tried clearing Edge data and resetting Edge settings, but it didn't fix the issues; it looks like something is kept even when Edge is cleared and reset.

I absolutely don't want to recreate my user profile, I have tons of stuff and settings which I definitely don't want to migrate over.

How can I *really* fully reset Edge?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird issues with Edge when Bing is not the default search engine](https://superuser.com/questions/1647708/weird-issues-with-edge-when-bing-is-not-the-default-search-engine)

Comment: Rather than open a new question, edit the original question, which I've tried to answer.

Comment: As I said *multiple times*, I absolutely don't want to recreate my whole user profile. I want to fix what's wrong with Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fully reset Edge by doing the following:

1. (Optional) - Use profile sync as a backup of your personal data, passwords, history, Favorites, etc; *don't* synchronize Edge settings and extensions.
2. Cose all Edge Windows.
3. Use Regedit to search for "edge" and delete everything Edge-related from your user profile.
4. Go to your user profile's `Appdata` directory, search for the word "edge" and delete
   everything Edge-related.
5. Start Edge; it will perform its initial configuration.
6. Configure all Edge settings as you wish, including (if desiderd) your default search engine.
7. (Optional) - Use profile sync to recover all the data you synchronized in step 1.

With this proceure, Edge was fully reset to factory default and all the weird issues I've been experiencing disappeared; the profile sync allowed me to keep my important data such as web credentials, history, favorites, personal info and payment methods.

All cookies were of course lost lost, thus I had to login again to all web sites; but the saved credentials helped a lot here.